# How to get privileges according to current user role

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How to get current users privileges in wordpress a plugin with respect to their roles;

Eg:-

if input is `editor` function should return `delete_others_posts`, if input is `author` result will be `delete_published_posts` and so on...

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you are going to do with that could you explain further

Answer (score 1):

Get the name of the current user role :

```
function get_current_user_role() {
   global $current_user;
   return array_shift($current_user->roles);
}
```

Then using get_role($role_name) function you can get an array with all his capabilities.

E.G :  `$capabilities = get_current_user_role();`

Another solution is to use the current_user_can($capability_name) function that return true or false

For entire explanations : http://tomarea.fr/wordpress-roles-capacites-utilisateurs/

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on koma182's answer, wrap `get_role()` with a `var_dump` or `print_r` and you'll see the capabilites of the current user role:

```
function get_current_user_role() {
    global $current_user;
    return array_shift($current_user->roles);
}
```

and then where you call the function:

```
var_dump(get_role(get_current_user_role()));
```

Thanks Koma!